# Sum of variances of multinomial distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, parameter-estimation, multinomial-coefficients

I've k fair coins, and I would like to know the number of heads obtained in $n$ trials. But that is simple binomial distribution. But if I want to find out how much it varies from binomial expectation, them it becomes a multinomial distribution for the number of heads from 0 to k.
 $$ \text{pdf} = \frac{n!}{x_0!\cdots x_k!}p_0^{x_0}\cdots p_k^{x_k} $$
Where:
$$ p_i =  {k \choose i}\frac{1}{2^k}$$

I am interested in:
$$ \text{Var}(\vec{X}) = \sum_{i=0}^k E(X_i - E[\vec{X}]_i)^2$$

Since we have:
$$ \text{Var}(X_i) = E(X_i - E[X_i])^2 = np_i(1-p_i)$$

The wrong derivation is as follows, how do I correct this. This I think is wrong due to dependency or number of degrees problem. 
$$ \text{Var}(\vec{X}) = \sum_{i=0}^k\text{Var}(X_i) = \sum_{i=0}^k np_i(1-p_i)$$

on substitution we get:
$$ \text{Var}(\vec{X}) = n(1-{2k \choose k}) \approx n(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi~k}})$$

How do I correct this? Experimental data (for k=15) seem to differ a bit. In the following graph RMS is defined as:

$$ \text{RMS} = \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\text{Var}(\vec{X})}$$

[image: Experimental Data]

The IJulia code used to generate this is: [here](https://github.com/anitasv/stats-class/blob/master/Statistics%20Class%20-%203.ipynb)

Comment: It looks like you're missing a covariance term for $X_i,X_j$ since they aren't quite independent.

Comment: I know about the dependency hence the confusion. Covariance term comes only if I'm finding variance of sum of the values.

Comment: Is your variance formula for $\vec{X}$ correct? What I mean is, shouldn't there be some kind of covariance there? On the other hand, if it's a definition, then what do you mean by wrong derivation? What should the answer be?

Comment: Probably. But what should it be?

Comment: My derivation is probably correct, I am just being paranoid. The experiment goes like this, take k trials of a fair coin. You get 0 to k heads. What is the expected variance from binomial expectation? I've attached a picture for k=15 from experiment and using equation.

Comment: I think I found out the mistake, my experimental setup is doing expectation of standard deviation and not of variance, hence the minor difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the derivation, only problem with experimental setup. The experiment is calculating expected value of standard deviation and not of variance.

Change

```
RMSExptAvg(S, n) = mean([RMSExpt(S, n) for i in 1:10000]))
```

to this:

```
RMSExptAvg(S, n) = sqrt(mean([RMSExpt(S, n)^2 for i in 1:10000]))
```

Then equations match up exactly.

Getting closed form equation for expectation of standard deviation is pretty difficult.